# How to Re-direct Console.Writeline() messages from a dll to Winform listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

My dll has some real-time messages which are printed out using:

```
Console.Writeline("XYZ Message");
```

I have referenced this dll in my C# Windows form application.
The messages are then printed out in real-time using:

```
public MyClientMainForm()
{
  AllocConsole();
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

But using this way I am launching a separate console window for displaying the messages.

Instead of a separate Console window, I wish to re-direct these messages to a `Listbox` inside my Winform.

Can someone help me with a simple example for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting Console Output to winforms ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780606/redirecting-console-output-to-winforms-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

[Redirect Console.WriteLine to String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11911734/2757497)
Maybe, This way you can convert your output to String and from String you can convert to ListBox using `listBox1.Items.Add(stringName);`

Answer (score -1):

Another, probably cleaner way to do this is to extend TextWriter with your own that logs to wherever you'd like it to.

Note: I have not tested this.

```
public class ListBoxWriter : TextWriter
{
private ListBox list;
private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

public ListBoxWriter(ListBox list)
{
    this.list = list;
}

public override void Write(char value)
{
    base.Write(value);
    content.Append(value);
    if (value == '\n')
    {
        list.Items.Add(content.ToString());
        content = new StringBuilder();
    }
}

public override Encoding Encoding
{
    get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
}
}
```

Comment: This answer is just copy-pasted from [Redirecting Console Output to winforms ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1780647/324260) without adding any context.

Comment: @rishit_s Where should the extended public class ListBoxWriter : TextWriter be placed in the Winform code? And will this be fine:      public partial class MyClientMainForm : Form
     {
      TextWriter writer;
      public MyClientMainForm()
      {
       InitializeComponent();
       writer = new ListBoxWriter(MyListBox);
       Console.SetOut(writer);
      }
      ...
     }//class ends